# C++ s.replace wont replace "." with ".\n"

Tags: c++, string, replace, while-loop

I a have so far added two find and replace, and it works all good. But when i add the third find and replace, to add a \n where ever a dot is found, the whole console output becomes blank. All text dissapears. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is the code I want to add, to replace "." with ".\n", which causes the print to become blank.

```
while (t1.find(".") != string::npos)
    t1.replace(t1.find("."), 3, ".\n");
```

This is the rest of the code that works all godd, before I add the third find and replace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");
    string const txt1 = "Foten är en kroppsdel som förekommer mycket i våra uttryck.";
    string const txt2 = "På stående fot betyder omedelbart, utan förberedelse.";
    string const txt3 = "Försätta på fri fot betyder att ge någon friheten.";
    string const txt4 = "Sätta foten i munnen betyder att göra bort sig.";
    string const txt5 = "Få om bakfoten betyder att missuppfatta något.";
    string const txt6 = "Skrapa med foten betyder att visa sig underdånig eller ödmjuk.";
    string const txt7 = "Stryka på foten betyder att tvingas ge upp.";
    string const txt8 = "Leva på stor fot betyder att föra ett dyrbart eller slösaktigt leverne.";
    string const txt9 = "Varför fick du foten???";

    string t1 = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6 + txt7 + txt8 + txt9;

    while (t1.find("fot") != string::npos)
        t1.replace(t1.find("fot"), 3, "hand");

    while (t1.find("Fot") != string::npos)
        t1.replace(t1.find("Fot"), 3, "Hand");

    cout << t1;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I don't know C++, but maybe it is using Regular Expressions; And so `.` in RegExp significate "One character of any kind". So it should maybe have changed all your text to series of "\n".

Comment: I actually believa that you are right. How should i make it understand that it is a dot?

Comment: Maybe try escaping the dot like `"\."`

Comment: @NatNgs: `replace` doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for infomation. So my proposition will not fix your problem @Thesar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't search string from front after you replace string!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void string_replace_all(std::string& target, std::string_view search_str, std::string_view replace_str)
{
    for(
        //find first search_str in target
        std::size_t pos = target.find(search_str);
        //When pos == std::string::npos, not match was found. 
        pos != std::string::npos;
        // Pos is front of last replaced string.
        // pos + replace_str.size() is just after replaced string.
        // We need to search string from there to avoid infinity loop.
        pos = target.find(search_str, pos + replace_str.size())
    ){
        target.replace(pos, search_str.size(), replace_str);
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");
    std::string const txt1 = "Foten är en kroppsdel som förekommer mycket i våra uttryck.";
    std::string const txt2 = "På stående fot betyder omedelbart, utan förberedelse.";
    std::string const txt3 = "Försätta på fri fot betyder att ge någon friheten.";
    std::string const txt4 = "Sätta foten i munnen betyder att göra bort sig.";
    std::string const txt5 = "Få om bakfoten betyder att missuppfatta något.";
    std::string const txt6 = "Skrapa med foten betyder att visa sig underdånig eller ödmjuk.";
    std::string const txt7 = "Stryka på foten betyder att tvingas ge upp.";
    std::string const txt8 = "Leva på stor fot betyder att föra ett dyrbart eller slösaktigt leverne.";
    std::string const txt9 = "Varför fick du foten???";

    std::string t1 = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6 + txt7 + txt8 + txt9;

    string_replace_all(t1, "fot", "hand");
    string_replace_all(t1, "Fot", "Hand");
    string_replace_all(t1, ".", ".\n");


    std::cout << t1;


    return 0;

}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/KejSz05Ja0bu9mN8

Comment: std::string_view won't work. Says that std doesnt have a member 'string_'view'?

Comment: std::string_view is C++17's new library. if you don't have C++17 environment, replace `std::string_view` to `std::string`(allocation occur). Or, if you can use boost, replace to `boost::string_view`

Comment: Thank you, it worked now :). Can you by any chance refer to somewhere i can read about this void replace_all that is in the beginning of the code. Just so i understand what it does, thus easier to remmeber afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You get into an endless loop. `t1.find(".") != string::npos` remains `true` forever because you keep inserting a `'.'` into the string as part of the `".\n"` replacement.

The solution is to start every new `find` search in the loop only *after* the contents which `replace` has inserted.

---

You might want to use [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/string_algo.html) for this, by the way. It then becomes a simple matter of `boost::replace_all(t1, ".", ".\n");`.

Comment: Wow, how didn't I see that. So dumb of me. I have also tried to instead insert \n behind every , but it does not work either.

Do you have any solution tips?